# can't get image from props react

Tags: reactjs

here i'm using map to sending <> as an object to other component

```
<CartItem key={item.id} {...item} removeItem={removeItem} />
```

and here displaying some properties of that object but can't access to "full_background", the error i'm getting is UNDEFINED

```
<img src={full_background} alt="product" />
<li>{name} x{quantity} = ${quantity * price}</li>
```

i tried directly catching it from props like "props.full_background" but still didn't get anything. there should be image source cause i'm using it in other component

Comment: Log the object in the component containing the `map` method call and verify if the `full_background` property is defined.

Comment: Can you show the CartItem component code as well and also the screenshot of the error

Comment: you were right, it's not defined even in the component containing `map`, I'll check once more. thanks a lot